# Pandas indexed DataFrame to csv: Writing x cols but got y aliases

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.6.9 and Pandas 0.24.2

I am saving a DataFrame to CSV using the following code:

```
df.to_csv(price_filename, header=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adjusted_close', 'Volume'], index=True)
```

I get the following error:

> Writing 6 cols but got 7 aliases

This is what my DataFrame looks like:

```
              Open    High     Low   Close  Adjusted_close  Volume                                                                            
Date
2020-10-16  618.50  630.75  615.50  625.25          625.25       0
2020-10-15  596.75  619.50  596.50  618.25          618.25   90299
2020-10-14  594.75  600.25  587.25  596.75          596.75   58370
2020-10-13  596.25  604.25  590.75  594.00          594.00   56418
2020-10-12  592.50  599.00  587.00  594.25          594.25   63837
```

I understand that there is a mismatch between the number of columns in the df and the list passed into the `header` variable. However, I have the index flag set to True but the error occurs. Similarly, removing the index flag does not resolve the issue.

How do I save the file to CSV with the columns specified in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index_label` para

```
df.to_csv(price_filename, header=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adjusted_close', 'Volume'], index_label="Date")
```

Or

We can reset index first using [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df.reset_index().to_csv(price_filename, header=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adjusted_close', 'Volume'], index=False)
```

Comment: You need to add an index=False to the `to_csv()` function before it saves in the required format

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Better i just found `index_label` para in `to_csv`..